# How to appendChild as third child

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add a new child node, after a specified node, as the third child node.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>tow</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>

<script>
var li = document.createElement("li");
document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(li);
var sometext = document.createTextNode("third one");
li.appendChild(sometext); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

keep in mind that there is a difference in `childNodes`, namely `siblings` and `ElementSiblings`. a `textNode` is a `Node`, but not an `Element`. so if you want to insert an element into the the DOM, use `nextElementSibling` | `previousElementSibling` and `appendChild` | `insertBefore` and the parent's `children` attribute that only contains Elements like this:

```
function insertAsThird( element, parent ){
  if ( parent.children.length > 2 ){
   parent.insertBefore(element, parent.children[2]);
 }
 else parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
insertAsThird( yourThirdElement, document.getElementById("your target parent"));
```

if you want to to work on childNodes, not Elements, just change the `parent.children` parts to `parent.childNodes`

Comment: You don't need the `parent.children.length` test. Just go ahead and do `parent.insertBefore(element, parent.children[2])`, and if there aren't enough children, it will behave just like `.appendChild()`. http://jsfiddle.net/4zU2c/

Answer (score 5):

Use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) if you want to add a node anywhere before the end of its container.

```
parentElement.insertBefore(newNode, currentThirdNode);
```

Comment: No. Nothing appears to be missing from the answer. If there is something you don't understand, please be more specific about what it is you don't understand.

Comment: I'm trying to add the created element as third child not as last child as the code example

Comment: @FahmyFarahat — You've just repeated the question, which this answer already answers. If there is something (*in the answer*) that you don't understand, please be **more specific** about what it is you don't understand.

Comment: 1) Retrieve the third `<li>` element: `var third_li = menu.getElementsByTagName('li')[2];` 2) Insert the new element before the current one: `menu.insertBefore(new_li, third_li);`

Answer (score 1):

javascript (without jQuery):

```
var newLi = document.createElement("li");
newLi.innerHTML ="new el 3"
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var el3 = menu.getElementsByTagName("li")[2];
menu.insertBefore(newLi, el3);
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#menu').children().eq(1).append('<li>new</li>');
```

Comment: This question isn't tagged `jQuery`, so I wouldn't post this here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should append the textNode before adding the new element like this:

```
<script>
  var li = document.createElement("LI");
  var sometext = document.createTextNode("third one");
  li.appendChild(sometext);

  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  var third = parent.getElementsByTagName("LI")[2];

  menu.insertBefore(li, third);
</script>
```

I Hope this works for you..

Comment: why do you use capitalized letters?

Comment: Well, from my experience, browsers such as IE wouldn't recognize the element you're trying to create unless you capitalize them..

Comment: That's false. HTML tag names are not case sensitive.

Comment: Do you have IE 6? Well you might be right, but I like applying/adopting Good practices when programming. I've had problems with IE's javascript engine before. It wan't a funny experience..

Comment: Well I'll say that XHTML requires lowercase for tag name, so that whenever I write HTML and XHTML I just use lowercase.